# Javascript: Can only get nodeValue() not value() from an input?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, getelementbyid, nodevalue

I have the following `HTML` Input:

```
<input type="number" id="input-number"/>
```

In my `JS` code below, when I try to do `.value` on `userInput` I cannot do so, I can only do `.nodeValue`.

Why is this?

```
// elements on page
const userInput = document.getElementById('input-number');
const addBtn = document.getElementById('btn-add');
const subtractBtn = document.getElementById('btn-subtract');
```

Comment: Without a [mcve] I don't think we can say.

Comment: I'm guessing it's because you're trying to access `val`, which isn't a property on html elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found it's working fine here. You can check this example.

```js
const userInput = document.getElementById('input-number');
const addBtn = document.getElementById('btn-add');
const subtractBtn = document.getElementById('btn-subtract');

addBtn.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  userInput.value++;
})

subtractBtn.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  userInput.value--;
})
```

```html
<input type="number" value=0 id="input-number"/>
<button id="btn-add">+</button>
<button id="btn-subtract">-</button>
```